# HingeJoint doesnt open the opposite direction

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was wondering if you could tell me if this is possible. I've spent a couple hours to no avail trying to find a way to make a object with box collider swing inwards and outwards like a door. I used hinge joint, but it will only swing the gameobject inwards or outwards around the joint. I am trying to achieve a 'saloon door' effect that allows free rotation around the y axis.  I have tried fiddling with the anchor position and axis values but no luck. I was surprised not to find any similar problems online, perhaps hinge joint is not meant for this purpose? Any clarification is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure how I fixed it, but I got the door to swing freely. One possible reason is surrounding colliders or terrain prevented it from swinging freely. *sigh*